# Mongo MapReduce - Checking the Standard Output

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am trying to execute mongo mapreduce commands via the java api - com.mongodb.MapReduceCommand . Prior to this, when I was executing the command via the mongo shell, I was able to view the output from the standard output stream. When I invoke the command via the java api, how could I check for any output for progress/error info ?

I have enabled the verbosity to true (by default) .

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MapReduceCommand is blocking, so there is no way to check the progress. However, you can use MapReduceOutput class to capture the result of a map/reduce operation.